# Display Rows With Styles

Tags: php

So I've been working on a statistic page where rows from the database get displayed into the actual page. Everything works fine with it displaying all the rows from the database but the thing is that i want to change the style for each row when it's displayed there FX: this rows color is blue and the others is green (each one contains a username). Now the PHP code echo's the rows one by one & also the html code each time a new record is made. Take a look at this image : [how the rows look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRD6n.png)

The thing i want to do is to display each username 1 in a different style and one in the other style without duplicating them. Take a look at the code to understand better :

```
<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT username, prize, date FROM enter";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// THE IMPOARTANT PART----------

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<tr class="hscrB"><td><img src="./ Charity Contributors_files/ICON.ico" alt=""> <a class="user-link" style="" target="_blank">'. '' . $row["username"].  '</span></td></tr><tr class="hscrG"><td><img src="./ Charity Contributors_files/ICON.ico" alt=""> <a class="user-link" style="" target="_blank">'  . $row["username"]. '';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Could someone solve this issue? And make the next username appear in the different styled row?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to clearly understand your question but I think that you should not do this in PHP. Coloring the rows differently alternatively is a job for CSS, which can do it quite easily. Take a look:

```css
tr:nth-child(even) { background: red; }
tr:nth-child(odd) { background: green; }
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child to understand how `:nth-child` can be used to do this.

--

However, if you really want to achieve this in PHP, then you should use a boolean that inverts itself each time you show a row, like this simplified example:

```php
$even = true;
while ($condition)
{
  // assigning a different class depending on $even variable.
  echo '<tr class="hscr'. $even ? "B" : "G" .'"><td>testing</td></tr>';
  $even = !$even; // if $even was true, it is now false. if $even was false, is is now true.
}
```